# Weird beahaviour of string pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{ 
  char*m ;
  m="srm";  
  printf("%d",*m); 
  return 0; 
}
```

The output is 115.  Can someone explain why it gives 115 as output?

Comment: Because that is the ASCII value of the letter 's'

Comment: what output were you expecting?

Answer (score 6):

`*m` is the same as `m[0]`, i.e. the first element of the array pointed to by `m` which is the character `'s'`.

By using the `%d` format specifier, you're printing the given argument as an integer.  The ASCII value of `'s'` is 115, which is why you get that value.

If you want to print the string, use the `%s` format specifier (which expects a `char *` argument) instead and pass the pointer `m`.

```
printf("%s\n", m);
```

Comment: what if i want to print the string. will %s will do?

Comment: @vasusingh `%s` along with `m` as the argument, not `*m`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, 
the first one is that you're trying to add three bytes to a char, a char is one byte.
the second problem is that char *m is a pointer to an address and is not a modifiable lvalue.  The only time you should use pointers is when you are trying to point to data

example:

```
char byte = "A"; //WRONG
char byte = 0x61; //OK
char byte = 'A'; //OK
//notice that when setting char byte = "A" you will recieve an error, 
//the double quotations is for character arrays where as single quotes,
// are used to identify a char
enter code here
char str[] = "ABCDEF";
char *m = str;

printf("%02x", *m); //you are pointing to str[0]
printf("%02x", *m[1]); //you are pointing to str[1]
printf("%02x", *m[1]); //you are pointing to str[1]
printf("%02x", *(m + 1)); //you are still pointing to str[1]
//m is a pointer to the address in memory calling it like
// *m[1] or *(m + 1) is saying address + one byte
//these examples are the same as calling (more or less)
printf("%02x", str[0]); or 
printf("%02x", str[1]);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, when using printf, if you want to print an array of characters use %s as mentioned by other users, if you use printf %s the character array MUST be null terminated

Comment: by pointing to a pointer you are actually derefrencing it, so *m[1]  would return the value of str[1], m[1] is going to return I believe part of the address, or garbage I'm not sure which

Comment: No, `m` contains a pointer to the first element of `str`.  The syntax `m[1]` is exactly equivalent to `*(m+1)` as per section 6.5.2.1p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: if it is exactly equivalent to *(m+1) then why are you considering it invalid instead of shorthand, 6.5.2.1p2 states that it is nothing more then a subscripted designation, meaning it's literally shorthand?

Comment: In the example, I put both ways and even stated that they are the same...

Comment: `*(m+1)` is fine.   `*m[1]` is **not**.  It translates to `**(m + 1)`.  `m` is a `char *`, so `m + 1` is also a `char *`, making `*(m+1)` == `m[1]` a `char`, which makes `**(m+1)` == `*m[1]` invalid because you can't dereference a `char` as if it were a pointer.

Comment: The code you posted fails to compile for exactly this reason.

Comment: by golly you're right. I'll have to read that document you posted and try to get a better under standing I suppose. I thought I had it pretty much down packed :/

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and arrays act similarly .Array names are also pointers pointing to the first element of the array.
You have stored "srm" as a character array with m pointing to the first element.
"%d" will give you the ASCII value of the item being pointed by the pointer.
ASCII value of "s" is 115.
if you increment your pointer (m++) then print it's ascii value , output will be ascii value of "r" - 114.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{ 
  char *m ;
  m="srm"; 
  m++;       //pointing to the 2nd element of the array
  printf("%d",*m);   //output = 114
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.  Rest of answer OK.